# Job with SSIS as second step doesn't wait until SSIS has finished

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-job

I have a job that has 3 steps: T-SQL, SSIS Package, then another T-SQL. The SSIS Package imports data from another source into a table. I'm running into a problem because the third step isn't waiting for the SSIS Package to finish running. Can I somehow make that step wait on the package to complete? Or, alternatively, can I add that t-SQL to the package itself so it runs the statement after it's done?

The job step looks like this: Can I add the synchronized parameter to it somehow?

```
    /****** Object:  Step [Import Data from AMS]    Script Date: 07-12-2019 2:11:33 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Import Data from AMS', 
        @step_id=2, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=3, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/FILE "\"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Intranet\Patrick\SSIS Packages\Export_custhist.dtsx\"" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=32
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
```

Comment: This is unusual. I've build literally dozens of jobs that follow a similar pattern, and they always wait for package completion to move on. What's the package doing?

Comment: The package gets data from an oracle database and inserts it into the local sql server one. I can tell it's still running after the job finishes though because the row count continues to increase.

Comment: In my current environment, I'm using SSISDB for deployment, so my connections don't include the parameter noted in the link, but there might be something useful here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545401/how-can-i-wait-for-an-ssis-package-to-complete